# How do I change NA to 0 in R

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to change N/A in a data frame to 0, I tried this:

```
adv[is.na(adv)]=0
```

and I got this:

> In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = 0) :
>     invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: If `adv` is a frame, then you should likely be doing this to one or more columns of said frame instead of the frame as a whole. While the code works, there is room for ambiguity here if you have non-numeric columns.

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, there are `factor` columns, which needs to be converted to `character` first

```
i1 <- sapply(adv, is.factor)
adv[i1] <- lapply(adv[i1], as.character)
```

Now, it can be converted to 0

```
adv[is.na(adv)] <- 0
```

---

`is.na` works only when the value is `NA` and not `"N/A"`.  It is better to read with `na.strings` in `read.csv/read.table`

```
adv <- read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = "N/A", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
adv[is.na(adv)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
as.numeric(is.na(adv))
```